# Images not attaching to email

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent

I'm trying to add multiple images to an email intent. This is the code that I've been using.

```
    final ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < form.getImageContainers().size(); i++)
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(form.getImageContainers().get(i).getImagePath())));

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "pdlmob@auburn.edu")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Submission (Beta Test)")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(buildBody()));
            .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

But it doesn't attach anything, just the body text and everything else goes.

I tried getting a single image by replacing the `.putParcelableArrayListExtra` with this line

```
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(form.getImageContainers().get(0).getImagePath())));
```

And it did attach the image, so I can tell the there's nothing wrong with the string that stores the path. Unfortunately I can't loop through and just use that line for each image, since it will only use the last one (tried it). I've read answers that use this method, and others that use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, but that gives me an empty picker that tells me I don't have any apps that can perfom the action.

Any reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and `setType("text/plain")`, so my first line now looks like

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).setType("text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add multiple images to an email intent

`ACTION_SEND` does not support multiple streams. [`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` does](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE). So, when the `ACTION_SEND` app tries to get `EXTRA_STREAM`, either they crash or get `null` back, because they will not be calling `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` or the equivalent, because they are expecting the value to be a `Uri`, not an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects.

> I've read answers that use this method, and others that use Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, but that gives me an empty picker that tells me I don't have any apps that can perfom the action.

That is because you do not not have any apps that can perform the action, apparently. Just because apps support `ACTION_SEND` does not mean that they have to support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: Gmail can't support multiple?

Comment: @CodyHarness: Apparently not, though you'll help your cause if you call `setDataAndType()` and provide the MIME type of your content. You may be tempted to call `setType()` instead, but that wipes out the `Uri` you are providing in the constructor.